# ScrollView snap to center

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to setup my scrollView like this video (I know in video use collectionview bu for some reason I want convert this effect to scrollView)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kj6xgj68gz6258p/ScreenRecording_06-26-2018%2019-15-43.MP4

3 important thing:

1. scroll must snap to center when scrolling
2. resize current item (forward item is bigger than backward item)
3. swift

UPDATE:

```
var ScrollView = UIScrollView()

var arr : Array<UIColor> = [.red,.blue,.green]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(ScrollView)

    ScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.size.width).isActive = true
    ScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320).isActive = true

    ScrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    ScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false

    ScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    ScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 3.0 * self.view.frame.size.width, height: 320)
    ScrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width, y: 0)


    ScrollView.center = self.view.center

    for i in 0..<3 {
        let viewBG = UIView()
        viewBG.backgroundColor = arr[i]

        if (i == 0) {
            viewBG.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i) + 125, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width - 100, height: 320)
        } else if(i == 1) {

            viewBG.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i) + 50, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width - 100, height: 320)
        } else {

            viewBG.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i) - 25, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width - 100, height: 320)
        }



        ScrollView.addSubview(viewBG)
    }
}
```

thanks guys

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: dear @AndréSlotta I update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use iCarousal. It is easy to implement and Swift example is also available.

Following is link - 
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel